# Different exceptions in the same situations MFC/Sql

Tags: c++, sql, mfc, odbc

I'm using CRecordSet class to execute select query. I want to handle situation when I loose connection to database. I simulate this by turning off database. In most cases I receive "Connection failure" in catch which is correct. However sometimes, I get "Query timeout expired - State:S1T00,Native:0" and this is the only exception. Any idea why ? How can I detect when connection is lost if I get "Query timeout"? I use MS SQL Server 2014 and MFC. I will be grateful for all help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it will depend on how much time you wait to make the test.

Try set a known timeout with:
CDatabase::SetQueryTimeout()

...and test the conection before and after to see if the exceptions are consistent when the timeout expires and when it doesn´t.